# Port forwarding router to listen on node.js server on home computer

Tags: dns, routing, port-forwarding, node.js

I have a domain name: www.domain.com

I went to my registrar that holds that domain name and logged in. I setup a DNS record type A with my public IP address.

Now if I go to www.domain.com, I'm directed to my router's homepage. Now all I should have to do is port forward my router to my node.js server that is running on localhost:3000.

Picture for reference:

[image]

The IP address should be my computer's IP I got from entering `ifconfig` into the terminal. So I enter my computer's IP, and `3000` for the port start and port end fields.

Now if I go to my www.domain.com, I still get the homepage for my router. So the port forwarding is what I assume is incorrect. Does anyone have an idea what ports I should be entering? Or is it something entirely different?

Comment: Www.domain.com is looking at port 80 most likely and http traffic, and has nothing to do with port 3000 node.js traffic

Comment: Your image shows that there are no port forwarding rules defined. Are you sure that you have created a rule? The other thing to check is the remote management link on the left. You'll want to disable it (remote management).

Comment: @Tyson I've tried setting my server to listen in on port 80 as well. I changed the fields accordingly, but nothing is different. Do you have a solution that might work? I'm at a loss.

Comment: @chuex Yes I have applied the rule. I just showed the pic as a reference. And yes the remote management was always disabled.

Answer (score -1):

On local port and ip section put your pc ip and port and on remote port and ip put all ip addresses and port 80 as default http port is 80 so the browser will request the page on port 80 and if you are giving port 3000 the browser won't get a response.